# Efficiently Updating SwiftUI State Array

Tags: arrays, swift, swiftui

I have a small `State` array (~100 in size, but with a user customizable max-size) that gets updated very frequently. At peak network load, the array is updated ~30 to 40 times over a few seconds (it's all coming from an IRC server). Each time a new item is received, if the array is at the max-size, then the first element gets removed and the new element is added.

Is this implementation the most efficient for what I am trying to achieve, or is there something I can do with SwiftUI to implement something like a batch update? I've also seen some threads talk about copying the array, then setting the state to that new (modified) copy?

```swift
struct Component: View, ItemReceiver {
  @State var messages: [Message] = []

  var body: some View {
    ScrollView(.vertical) {
      ForEach(messages, id: \.id) { messageItem in
        Message(from: messageItem)
      }
    }
  }

  func onMessageItemReceived(_ newMessage: Message) {
    if (messages.count == 100) {
      self.messages.removeFirst()
    }
    self.messages.append(newMessage)
  }
}
```

Where the actual `Message` struct conforms to `Identifiable`, `Equatable`, and `Hashable`.

Comment: It's not the most efficient, since changing `@State` variables have a cost. But more importantly, do you need to update the view every 1/50 second? I don't think a User would appreciate the UI ;) . You may want to ensure that view updates occur at a reasonable frequency no matter how many events arrive to the system. You may consider to add some Swift Combine logic outside your view that handles throttling, debouncing and coalescing of those events.

Comment: Hey @CouchDeveloper! The actual implementation is an IRC chat interface so a lot of frequent updates are quite common in the largest channels. Maybe ~50 was a bit of a high number though, it's likely more around a max of ~30 to 40 spread across 2 or 3 seconds. Thanks for the tip on Combine, I'll definitely read through some docs! I've heard of Combine before but never worked with it.

Comment: You may find, that [throttle] (https://developer.apple.com/documentation/combine/publisher/throttle(for:scheduler:latest:)) does what you want, if the values are the array of messages `[Message]`.  So, you handle every event, calculate/update the array of messages (elsewhere, i.e. some ViewModel), then send the array through `throttle` for the view to update.